# What is the Request permission code for FlashLight In Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to turn on or turn off flashlight in marshmallow6.0 for that need to give the permission while running time in android.I tried the request permission code but it's not working on it.

Code:

```
if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.FLASHLIGHT)  != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)  != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
            // user permission not granted
            // ask permission
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.FLASHLIGHT, Manifest.permission.CAMERA});
        }
        else{
            // user already provided permission
        }
```

(It's not working because I couldn't get the android.manifest.permission.FLASHLIGHT)

Anyone solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the device doesnot have flashlight

Comment: did you use feature

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

Comment: Yes, I used this permission in manifest file.